# Using PHP to select and pair two users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make an application that pairs two available users by selecting them randomly from a database and then making them unavailable (so they can't be selected again).

I was wondering how I could select them and then pair them?

I've got the following database structure.

```
USERS
| id        | autoincrement, primary key
| user_id   | user's ID
| connected | available, connecting, chatting


ROOMS
| id        | 
| room_name | 
| room_id   | 
| user_id   | first user connected
| user_id2  | second user connected
```

I'm not making rooms, I'm simply trying to pair users and send them to a room.

Comment: Sorry but your asking us to code your problem which is not our part, you should post your own code here that we could help to elaborate some bugs and give you an idea on how to debugged it.

Comment: agreeing with @ClintBugs, would also like to know what the difference between user_id and id is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean join the records?

You could do something like:

```
select * from rooms as r
left outer join users as u on r.user_id=u.id
left outer join users as u2 on r.user_id2=u2.id
where r.id=123
```

123 = a room id.

EDIT:

Here is a way to update a Rooms record with two random Users

```
UPDATE rooms
SET 
user_id=(SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1),
user_id2=(SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1),
where id=123
```

I have tested this and it seems to work.  This will keep you from having duplicate users:

```
UPDATE rooms
SET 
user_id=(SELECT u1.id FROM users as u1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1),
user_id2=(SELECT u2.id FROM users as u2 where user_id <> u2.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1)
where id=123
```

Comment: I think he is wanting a random select that returns two users who are 'available', an update marking the two chosen users as 'connecting', an insert assigning the two users to a room, and finally a second update marking both users as 'chatting'.

Comment: I like your rooms update, but wouldn't that query run the risk of supplying the same user_id for both users? Would there be a way to prevent that and still use the subqueries?

Comment: Yes it would be possible.  I updated my answer again, although I didn't test my most recent query.  Try it out and see if it works.  If it doesn't give you an error, then it should work and not have duplicate users.

Comment: Everything looks like it should work to me. The only issue I could foresee would be if a user_id was not returned by the first subquery, but by using the <> I don't think that would truly be an issue. I haven't got any tables to test with either so I'll go with looks good.

Comment: Brook, I just updated it again (this time I did test it).  I had to make a small change, but this query should do the trick.  Instead of checking u1.id, I'm comparing to user_id (from rooms).

Comment: Very Nice. Simple yet powerful.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` could be something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM `USERS`
WHERE connected = 'available'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2;
```

You would need to parse the resultset and assign the to user_ids to variables such as

```
$user_id1
$user_id2
```

The first `UPDATE` would be something like this:

```
UPDATE `USERS` 
SET connected = 'connecting'
WHERE user_id IN ($user_id1,$user_id2);
```

The `INSERT` would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `ROOMS` (room_name,room_id,user_id,user_id2)
VALUES ($room_name,$room_id,user_id,user_id2);
```

Finally the last `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE `USERS` 
SET connected = 'connected'
WHERE user_id IN ($user_id1,$user_id2);
```

Although you are probably going to want to lock rows I have not grasped that part of database management yet. For you purposes you might want to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you'll need three tables instead of two to implement your logic.

Consider my db schema

```
USERS
| id        | autoincrement, primary key
| user_id   | user's ID
| connected | available, connecting, chatting

ROOMS
| id        | 
| room_name | 

USERCHAT
| id        |
| user_id   | user's ID
| room_id   | room id
```

To get pair you can execute following query.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM USERS 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM USERCHAT)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2;
```

After selecting users you can simply insert them in ROOMS and USERCHAT tables. Using this schema you can also allow multiple users instead of two for chat.